# Drawbacks of Windows Azure Platform?

Tags: windows, cloud, azure

It seems that documents available now are only whitepapers from Microsoft. So I only heard about advantages of this platform. I want to know about its drawbacks. What components/features of Windows Azure/SQL Azure/AppFabric make you uncomfortable? Which ones do you want to change/improve?

Thank you so much for this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entierly sure on specific features but there are a few things that bother me about so called Cloud computing.

1. Loss of control over pretty much
   anything.  I know you can set things
   up but it's not quite the same is
   it?
2. Speed.  If I'm hosting my site in
   say the cloud and my data locally in
   Australia then there is going to be
   a speed issue in getting my data off of
   the web.
3. It's still too new and there aren't
   enough war stories yet.  Not enough
   people have experianced the bad to
   have either faund a way to fix it or
   to influence a fix.

I think item 3 is my biggest point.  I'm a huge early adopter in most things but when it comes to hosting into a new environment that is still fairly new then I'd like to wait and see what others are saying first.

I'd also like to see a few large reference sites to get an appreciation of speed.

Comment: Windows Azure Platform comes with geo-locate features, that help you locate your service/data on a data center that near you. That helps performance a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm missing two things: transactional message queues with the "only once" delivery (i.e.: MSMQ Azure) and faster management API. One of these is promised to be fixed later, for the other there is a [suggestion on uservoice for Azure](http://windowsazure.uservoice.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/763078-msmq-azure?ref=title).

As for everything else - it's really easy to develop and manage auto-scaling (self-tuning) and really efficient cloud applications with Windows Azure. EC2 and Rackspace weren't that friendly to me. Of course, there are rough edges (quite a few of these), as in any bleeding-edge technology, but it is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell me if my reasoning below is valid (I know very little of Azure).

As I understand it, when you build an Azure application you build it from bottom up with the cloud in mind (for example, resources like databases are handled diffrently in an Azure application than in your old standard application).

This means you cannot start to build an Azure application and then in the end decide to host it in the old fashioned way for some reason (maybe you're not happy with performance or whatever).

Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a question. You would have better results if you treat it as such. To answer your question, you only tie your architecture to Azure if you use Azure specific features, like blobs, tables, and queues, or the Azure service bus. It is possible to build an ASP.NET or MVC site that can run either on Azure or on a standard Windows server. There are some configuration differences, and there are restrictions placed on the configuration if you want to be compatible with Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Paras, I know your post is older but there is now a 50GB db SKU for SQL Azure.